# SSIS Best approach for a hierachy of records

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-migration, hierarchical-data

I'm using SSIS to migrate data from a legacy system to a replacement system. 
Both old and new systems have a hierarchy set up along the lines of Company has many sites, sites have many locations etc etc. Each file to be migrated will only contain one company.  Using SSIS, given that the ID of the site needs to ripple down to location and location ID to the levels below what is the best approach. I was thinking nested foreach loops but being to SSIS I have no idea if this is the right way to go. Perhaps I am missing some clever feature of SSIS that can handle this?

Comment: I would process them by the type of file/table. Create 3 foreach file loops in sequence. First load all company files, then all sites and as last all locations. No need to nest anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've used a version of the technique detailed in this article

http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2010/10/29/insert_parent_child_pattern1/

I created views in the source database that return the data I need including a guid I can use to get hold of the inserted ID from the target database. I then use this in a lookup transform to get the ID I need and populate this into the target table. I am going to create a dataflow for each level following this pattern. It is working fine for the first couple of layers of the hierachy.